# Use of race tokens when conquering new regions

Tags: small-world

When conquering a new region, do you deploy race tokens from other regions you have already conquered, or do you use your unused race tokens?

Answer (score 12):

You only use your unused race tokens (those you took into hand at the start of your turn). The only time you can take race tokens from already conquered spaces is 1) At end of turn when you can reallocate tokens on conquered spaces, and 2) At the start of the turn when you can take race tokens from conquered spaces into hand.

Answer (score 2):

It's a 3 step process:

1. You take as many tokens back into your hand as you wish (you can empty regions that way, giving them up), normaly you keep 1 token in the regions you want to keep.
2. You do your attack with the spare tokens you have.
3. When you don't want to attack anymore you can redistribue tokens (but this time you are not allow to give up regions).

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be helpful to think about the structure of a turn this way:

0) Decide whether to put your active race into Decline. If yes, then perform the "Going Into Decline" steps and end your turn.

1) Leave only 1 token in every one of your active-race regions. Pick up *ALL* the rest of them. This is your "hand" of active race tokens.

1a) Optionally pick up the last active race token from any of your regions and add them to your hand.

2) Conquer regions with tokens from your hand, until you are either out of legal moves or you decide to finish.

When you are finished conquering regions:

3) Collect your gold rewards.

4) Perform step 1 (but not 1a) again.

5) Place active race tokens from your hand onto the board, only into spaces which already contain an active race token.

6) End of Turn

Of course racial/special abilities will cause exceptions to the above, but this helps visualize what's really going on under typical circumstances.